# I run Code, it show the result then it immediately turn in to Not found

Tags: file-not-found

I ran the Code, it showed the result then it immediately turned in to "Not found". This code is about to calculate days in a given year that 's entered from the form. Can any one show me my mistake and solve it. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <label for="fname">year:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="no" name="fname"><br>
  <button onclick="nam('no')">choose</button>
</form>
<p>days of year</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function nam(id)
{
  var x=document.getElementById(id).value;
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
var jan = daysInMonth(1, x);
var feb = daysInMonth(2, x);
var maa = daysInMonth(3, x);
var apr = daysInMonth(4, x);
var mei = daysInMonth(5, x);
var jul = daysInMonth(6, x);
var jun = daysInMonth(7, x);
var aug = daysInMonth(8, x);
var sep = daysInMonth(9, x);
var okt = daysInMonth(10, x);
var nov = daysInMonth(11, x);
var dec = daysInMonth(12, x);
var dagen = jan + feb + maa + apr + mei + jul + jun + aug + sep + okt + nov + dec;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dagen;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995146/13833218) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your getting a 404 Not Found error becasue when the button is clicked the `form` is being submitted. Since this is not the behaviour you want, you can use `preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour from being executed.

Something like this should fix the issue:

```js
function nam(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById(id).value;

  var jan = daysInMonth(1, x);
  var feb = daysInMonth(2, x);
  var maa = daysInMonth(3, x);
  var apr = daysInMonth(4, x);
  var mei = daysInMonth(5, x);
  var jul = daysInMonth(6, x);
  var jun = daysInMonth(7, x);
  var aug = daysInMonth(8, x);
  var sep = daysInMonth(9, x);
  var okt = daysInMonth(10, x);
  var nov = daysInMonth(11, x);
  var dec = daysInMonth(12, x);
  var dagen = jan + feb + maa + apr + mei + jul + jun + aug + sep + okt + nov + dec;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dagen;
}

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="fname">year:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="no" name="fname"><br>
    <button onclick="nam(event, 'no')">choose</button>
  </form>
  <p>days of year</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have included the `input` inside the `form` when you click on the button it executes the `nam()` function and then submits the form.

To prevent this behavior you can change the button type to submit and call the `nam()` function when the user clicks on the button via `onsubmit` attribute and then pass in the `event` and the id of the element you which want the value. In your JavaScript you can use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Try the below snippet

```js
function nam(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var x = document.getElementById(id).value;

  function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  }
  var jan = daysInMonth(1, x);
  var feb = daysInMonth(2, x);
  var maa = daysInMonth(3, x);
  var apr = daysInMonth(4, x);
  var mei = daysInMonth(5, x);
  var jul = daysInMonth(6, x);
  var jun = daysInMonth(7, x);
  var aug = daysInMonth(8, x);
  var sep = daysInMonth(9, x);
  var okt = daysInMonth(10, x);
  var nov = daysInMonth(11, x);
  var dec = daysInMonth(12, x);
  var dagen = jan + feb + maa + apr + mei + jul + jun + aug + sep + okt + nov + dec;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dagen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form onsubmit="nam(event, 'no')">
    <label for="fname">year:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="no" name="fname"><br>
    <button type=submit>choose</button>
  </form>
  <p>days of year</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `<form>` tag. It will reload the page. Handle `nam` function from `onsubmit` in `<form>` tag. Else, don't use `<form>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="nam(event,'no')">
  <label for="fname">year:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="no" name="fname"><br>
  <button>choose</button>
</form>
<p>days of year</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function nam(e, id)
{
e.preventDefault();
  var x=document.getElementById(id).value;
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
var jan = daysInMonth(1, x);
var feb = daysInMonth(2, x);
var maa = daysInMonth(3, x);
var apr = daysInMonth(4, x);
var mei = daysInMonth(5, x);
var jul = daysInMonth(6, x);
var jun = daysInMonth(7, x);
var aug = daysInMonth(8, x);
var sep = daysInMonth(9, x);
var okt = daysInMonth(10, x);
var nov = daysInMonth(11, x);
var dec = daysInMonth(12, x);
var dagen = jan + feb + maa + apr + mei + jul + jun + aug + sep + okt + nov + dec;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dagen;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```